# Prefab won't change to custom shader

Tags: unity, shaders

I am writing here as I have encountered a problem with Unity. I have written my own surface shader and want to use it for a prefab. However, when I drag and drop the shader to the prefab in the editor, it recognizes it but it doesn't change the prefab. The prefab is a prefab for some objects which stays pink. What's the problem? The shader works, and I know that as I have tried to drag and drop the shader directly to some of the objects. In addition to that, I have also tried to create a material an drag and drop the shader that and then drag and drop the material to the prefab. That didn't work either.

Comment: Shader, Material, and Texture are different things.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the game isn't running and drag your prefab into a scene and select it in the Hierarchy.  There should be details in the *Inspector* that will allow you to apply your shader.

First, find the part of the prefab that contains a renderer (probably a `MeshRenderer`).  Under that component, there will be a "*Materials*" list which should have a size you can adjust and then elements to select the materials you'd like.

When your materials are set, there will be drop-down menus to select which shaders those materials are using; this is where you select the shader you want.

Finally, as with any adjustments to prefabs, you must click the "Apply" button in the upper right on the *Inspector*.  **If you make changes while the game is running or without clicking "Apply", the changes will not be saved to the prefab.**